# TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm getting the following error when performing recursive feature selection with cross-validation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../srl/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    argident_sys.train_classifier()
  File "/Users/.../srl/identification.py", line 194, in train_classifier
    feat_selector.fit(train_argcands_feats,train_argcands_target)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py", line 298, in fit
    ranking_ = rfe.fit(X[train], y[train]).ranking_
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

The code that generates the error is the following:

```
def train_classifier(self):

    # Get the argument candidates
    argcands = self.get_argcands(self.reader)

    # Extract the necessary features from the argument candidates
    train_argcands_feats = []
    train_argcands_target = []

    for argcand in argcands:
        train_argcands_feats.append(self.extract_features(argcand))
        if argcand["info"]["label"] == "NULL":
            train_argcands_target.append("NULL")
        else:
            train_argcands_target.append("ARG")

    # Transform the features to the format required by the classifier
    self.feat_vectorizer = DictVectorizer()
    train_argcands_feats = self.feat_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_argcands_feats)

    # Transform the target labels to the format required by the classifier
    self.target_names = list(set(train_argcands_target))
    train_argcands_target = [self.target_names.index(target) for target in train_argcands_target]

    ## Train the appropriate supervised model      

    # Recursive Feature Elimination
    self.classifier = LogisticRegression()
    feat_selector = RFECV(estimator=self.classifier, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(train_argcands_target, 10))

    feat_selector.fit(train_argcands_feats,train_argcands_target)

    print feat_selector.n_features_
    print feat_selector.support_
    print feat_selector.ranking_
    print feat_selector.cv_scores_

    return
```

I know I should also perform GridSearch for the parameters of the LogisticRegression classifier, but I don't think that's the source of the error (or is it?).

I should mention that I'm testing with around 50 features, and almost all of them are categoric (that's why I use the DictVectorizer to transform them appropriately).

Any help or guidance you could give me is more than welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's some training data examples:

```
train_argcands_feats = [{'head_lemma': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'dado', 'head': u'dado', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'postura', 'head': u'postura', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'maioria', 'head': u'maioria', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'querer', 'head': u'quer', 'head_postag': u'V-FIN'}, {'head_lemma': u'PT', 'head': u'PT', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'participar', 'head': u'participando', 'head_postag': u'V-GER'}, {'head_lemma': u'surpreendente', 'head': u'supreendente', 'head_postag': u'ADJ'}, {'head_lemma': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'revelar', 'head': u'revela', 'head_postag': u'V-FIN'}, {'head_lemma': u'recusar', 'head': u'recusando', 'head_postag': u'V-GER'}, {'head_lemma': u'maioria', 'head': u'maioria', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'PT', 'head': u'PT', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'participar', 'head': u'participando', 'head_postag': u'V-GER'}, {'head_lemma': u'surpreendente', 'head': u'supreendente', 'head_postag': u'ADJ'}, {'head_lemma': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'revelar', 'head': u'revela', 'head_postag': u'V-FIN'}, {'head_lemma': u'governo', 'head': u'Governo', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'de', 'head': u'de', 'head_postag': u'PRP'}, {'head_lemma': u'governo', 'head': u'Governo', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'recusar', 'head': u'recusando', 'head_postag': u'V-GER'}, {'head_lemma': u'maioria', 'head': u'maioria', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'querer', 'head': u'quer', 'head_postag': u'V-FIN'}, {'head_lemma': u'PT', 'head': u'PT', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'surpreendente', 'head': u'supreendente', 'head_postag': u'ADJ'}, {'head_lemma': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head': u'Bras\xedlia', 'head_postag': u'PROP'}, {'head_lemma': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head': u'Pesquisa_Datafolha', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'revelar', 'head': u'revela', 'head_postag': u'V-FIN'}, {'head_lemma': u'muito', 'head': u'Muitas', 'head_postag': u'PRON-DET'}, {'head_lemma': u'prioridade', 'head': u'prioridades', 'head_postag': u'N'}, {'head_lemma': u'com', 'head': u'com', 'head_postag': u'PRP'}, {'head_lemma': u'prioridade', 'head': u'prioridades', 'head_postag': u'N'}]

train_argcands_target = ['NULL', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'ARG', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'ARG', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'NULL', 'NULL']
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, the problem is inside your `feat_selector.fit(train_argcands_feats,train_argcands_target)` call. Is `RFECV` a class you create or is it a library? Is it possible to post your `RFECV.fit()` code?

Comment: @acattle It's a scikit-learn library: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html

Comment: @acattle where are you seeing that?

Comment: @möter I apologize. I misread the code. Comment removed.

Comment: It looks like the value of `train` in the line `anking_ = rfe.fit(X[train], y[train]).ranking_` is the problem, but it's impossible to determine how its value is determined without seeing all the rfe.py source code.

Comment: @Fernando Have you checked that the input to RFECV.fit has the right structure in compliance with the method's signature? TypeError might mean it's something along this line.

Comment: @martineau You can check the code of rfe.py here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py

Comment: It seems that there is a bug that I cannot reproduce the issue with dummy data. Could you please give a minimalistic list of python dictionaries and target values that trigger the issue?

Comment: @möter Yes, they are the same type as for any estimator. Now that you mention it, I think the problem starts with me not understanding what that TypeError means.

Comment: @Fernando you have the sources, you could insert some print statements within rfe.py to show you what the values are, or use a debugger.

Comment: @ogrisel Done! Hope that helps

Comment: @möter Yes, I'd probably start doing it.

Comment: Hmmm, the line numbers in the source you provided don't match the traceback. Ignoring that, the value of `train` what computed by `cv = check_cv(self.cv, X, y, is_classifier(self.estimator))` which is followed by a `for train, test in cv:` loop. Unfortunately the code for `check_cv()` is in an imported module that again I don't have the source to look at. Anyway, you should have the idea by now of what I'm trying to accomplish and be able to pursue the problem further on your own.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I finally got to solve the problem. Two things had to be done:

1. **train_argcands_target** is a list and it has to be a numpy array. I'm surprised it worked well before when I just used the estimator directly.
2. For some reason (I don't know why, yet), it doesn't work either if I use the sparse matrix created by the DictVectorizer. I had to, "manually", transform each feature dictionary to a feature array with just integers representing each feature value. The transformation process is similar to the one I present in the code for the target values.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is still interested,

I used the `CountVectorizer` on something very similar and it gave me the same error. I realized that the vectorizer gives me a COO sparse matrix which is basically a coordinate list. Elements in COO matrices can't be accessed through row indexes. It is best to convert it to a CSR matrix (Compressed Sparse Row) which indexes row-wise. The conversion can be done easily `coo_matrix.tocsr()`. No other change is required, this worked for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me. It is easier than retrieving doing the accepted answer out here. Also, the reason provided (COO inaccessible via row indices) makes much more sense.

Comment: Totally agree. COO is the problem.